# File Source Creation Time

Tags: c#, file

I have a project i'm working on where i need to verify the files in a local and a remote location machine. I have tried a couple of things. First i tried checking the CreationTimeUTC of both Files. I found out the creation time stores the time the file was created on the related file system, not the time the file was first created. As long as the file name matches and is the latest version. I dont "Really" want to read the entire contents and get an MD5 hash or some other form of identifier as reading the file may be impossible. (Getting the info of a file that's open by another program for example would make this method impossible)

So basically what i'm asking;
Is there anything stored within the file header that denotes the files creation time or anything like that? Or if anyone can recommend another setting to use or method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When each file is copied from the local machine to the remote machine, assign the file's creation time to a `string` using `File.GetCreationTime`, and then set creation time of the remote machine's copy with `File.SetCreationTime` so it matches with the creation time of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

The File creation time will always be depending on the machine it was created on. The easy solution is storing the File on machines you have control over and keep their time in sync.

On top of my head, I can think of two ways to solve your problem:

- Getting the remote and local system date time and using the
  difference between the two when comparing the files times.
- If the files are never deleted, you can always check their "lifetime"
  by calculating the time between the file creation and its last
  modification.

However, both strategies could be by-passed by manually changing the system date time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `File.GetLastWriteTime`? At least when copying a file from my laptop to my fileserver, LastWriteTime stayed the same.

(Looks like there is a known [conversion bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/26/80492.aspx) causing time and date information to sometimes have errors when copying from NTFS to FAT and vice versa though).